# Why wont my HTTP POST request send to my webpage?

Tags: java, php

Ive looked at a lot of other threads here and all over the internet and I cant seem to solve this..

So basically I have written this Java code:

```
public void sendReport(CommandSender sender, Player target, String reason)
{
    HttpURLConnection connectionStandard = null;
    String email = config.getString("rp.site.email");
    String password = config.getString("rp.site.password");
    String senderName = sender.getName();
    String targetName = target.getDisplayName();
    String reasonString = reason;

    try
    {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.website.net/folder/connect.php");    
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setRequestMethod("POST");
        request.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter post = new OutputStreamWriter(request.getOutputStream());
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email.toString(), "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password.toString(), "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("reporter", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(senderName, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("reported", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(targetName, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("reason", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reasonString, "UTF-8");
        post.write(data);
        post.flush();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        if(null != connectionStandard)
        {
            connectionStandard.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

and basically, my php code just looks like this:

```
<?php

 require_once "db.php";

 $reporter->startSecureSession();

 foreach ($_POST as $post => $value) {
  $post = strip_tags($post);
  $value = strip_tags($value);
 }

 if(!(isset($_POST['email'])) or (!isset($_POST['password'])) or (!isset($_POST['reporter'])) or (!isset($_POST['reported'])) or (!isset($_POST['reason']))) {
  exit("Invalid Request");
 }

 $password = hash("sha512", $_POST['password']);

 $reporter->login(array("email" => $_POST['email'], "password" => $password), "plugin");
 if($reporter->validateClient()) {

  $reporter->sendReport($_POST);
  header("Location: logout.php");
  exit();

 } else {
  exit();
 }

?>
```

When I send my details through chrome to the web page, it works and sends stuff to my database, but when I do it off my bukkit server through the command that sends the request, it doesnt :/

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache httpclient 4.x to send GET/POST request from Java.

```
String url = "http://www.website.net/folder/connect.php";
HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<BasicNameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.toString()));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.toString()));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reporter", senderName));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reported", targetName));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reason", reasonString));
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = null;
try {
    entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
method.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(method);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the javadoc of URLConnection:

> 1) The connection object is created by invoking the openConnection method
>   on a URL.
>
> 2) The setup parameters and general request properties are
>   manipulated.
>
> 3) The actual connection to the remote object is made, using
>   the connect method.
>
> 4) The remote object becomes available. The header
>   fields and the contents of the remote object can be accessed.

You do not appear to have called `URLConnection#connect`.

Comment: request.connect();

Where would I go about doing this? and where would i put the disconnect();